# Best set to build a tracked vehicle?

Tags: technic, tracks, tracked-vehicle

I want to build a tracked "all-terrain" vehicle myself (MOC), which should have the ability to climb over obstacles. Something alike https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXVO-wbWKxo

Now I'm looking for the technic model which has *"the best"* tracks to use. What would you recommend? It looks like I have the following options:

- http://brickset.com/sets/8043-1/Motorized-Excavator
- http://brickset.com/sets/42038-1/Arctic-Truck (is it even possible to combine multiple tracks into a bigger one?)
- http://brickset.com/sets/42042-1/Crawler-Crane

What's the recommendation?

Comment: Another set with a lot of track parts to consider: http://brickset.com/sets/42055 (comes out on August 1st)

Comment: Thanks for the information, this one is a little bit too big for my taste. I think I'm not going to buy this year's flagship model and will instead go for the Porsche GT3 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All 3 of the sets you listed actually use the same type of tracks, they are [*Technic, Link Tread Wide with Two Pin Holes* #57518](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57518).

In my opinion this type would be your best option for driving a robot for a number of reasons:

- Since they come as links the tracks can be made any length you want, allowing a lot of flexibility in designing the robot.  These are virtually the only link-based, variable-length tracks LEGO makes that would be suitable for driving a robot.
- They are *very* sturdy and do not break or come undone easily at all.
- They fit very securely on the cogs and practically never slip.  This is true even with a moderate degree of slack on the line, making it not necessary to measure the distances between/around the cogs to perfectly match the length of the track.

If you are going to be using these on your robot, you will need some cogs to drive them.  These tracks can be driven with the *Technic Tread Sprocket Wheels* [#57520](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57520) (small - 6T) and [57519](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57519) (large - 10T).

I would also recommend getting some [*Technic, Link Tread Attachment, Double, Rubber* #14149](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14149).  These handy little rubber grips fit on the tracks to give them better traction.  They work especially well on smooth, hard surfaces and for gripping stuff to climb over.

Comment: We just built the Crawler Crane and were very impressed with the treads.  Solid and no slipping as you said.  The net effect was that our crane acted more like a tank when going over surprisingly large obstacles.  Excellent design.